# Material design lite required validation on checkbox is not showing error message

Tags: checkbox, material-design-lite

I am using material design lite for a form. The issue that I'm facing is that when required validation is set on a checkbox, it seems to be hiding the error message as soon as it gets rendered.

Please note that the actual validation is working as expected, just the error message is not being displayed.

Here is a codepen with this issue - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVqPzm

Here is the HTML used:

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- Material Design Lite -->
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.2/material.min.js">    </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.2/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<!-- Material Design icon font -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body>
<form>
<label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="checkbox-1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="mdl-checkbox__input" required />
  <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Checkbox</span>
</label>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help regarding how to get the required validation message for checkbox to be displayed properly will be highly appreciated

Please note that this issue is specific to Chrome

Comment: This is expected behavior currently since built in validation doesn't adhere to MD specifications. However, we don't have an alternative internally since how errors with checkboxes and radios is not specified either.

Comment: After investigating a lot, I came to the same conclusion so I've moved to a custom error message implementation which seems to be doing the job for now.

@Garbee Will checkbox and radio validations be part of MD specifications any time soon?

Answer (score 1):

I made my CSS fix for this issue

```
.mdl-checkbox.is-upgraded .mdl-checkbox__input {
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  left: 2px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

Here is your pen updated > http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grGmZW

Comment: This fix works fine for a single check-box but not for a group of checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

problem is in CSS.

change

```
.mdl-checkbox.is-upgraded .mdl-checkbox__input {
position: absolute;
width: 0;
height: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
opacity: 0;
-ms-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
border: none; }
```

to

```
.mdl-checkbox.is-upgraded .mdl-checkbox__input {
position: absolute;
left:-9999px;
top:-9999px; }
```

This also works for radio.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What is your problem? What is your desired outcome?

Comment: The problem is that it is not possible to use required validation for checkboxes. I wanted to know if it was possible to handle checkbox validations (especially for group of checkboxes) using required